# Using history.js with Knockout and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, history.js

I have some filters on the left hand side of my page which use knockout and updates the results displayed using ajax when they are clicked. I would like to use history.js to maintain state such that if the user clicks back it will load the relevant content. This seems to work fine but knockout still has the filter checkboxes I selected ticked as I am using ko.observableArray() which gets added each time a filter is selected. How do I go about ensuring that the filter is unticked without a lot of code. I know it can be done by checking the url params and then comparing them to what is already in the array.

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on plnkr.co or similar service?

Comment: Here is a very simple example. Rather than use ajax to update it just updates with static data defined in the script. [link](http://run.plnkr.co/gJr558edo6MafKIM/)

Comment: Are you sure the link is valid? I get a 404.

Comment: Sorry seem as though it may have been incorrect [link](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/DdKvBTi6alvUnfebQKd6/) Correct one added.